# What is the rule of subject + gerund in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I was reading an article, and I noticed that the writer wrote a subject and after it a gerund. The sentence:

> For **graduates aiming** to become published authors, the prestigious Bridport Prize is a great place to begin.

Comment: For graduates [who are] aiming to become published authors. It's really a shortened verb form.

Comment: Try to parse it this way: "For **graduates** *aiming to become published authors*, the prestigious Bridport Prize is a great place to begin." The italicised part modifies the noun *graduates*.

Comment: It's not a gerund (nominal force): it's a participle (adjectival force qualifying "graduates"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For *graduates* **aiming to become published authors**, the prestigious Bridport Prize is a great place to begin.

The Noun - *graduates* - is being post modified by a Gerund-Participle clause - **aiming to become published authors**, and together form a Noun Phrase.

Comment: Incorrect. This is a *reduced relative clause*, which in non-reduced form reads: "*For graduates **who are aiming** to become published authors...*". Here, "aiming" is the present participle in present continuous, not a gerund or noun phrase, and I've never heard of a "gerund-participle clause", nor has Google.

Comment: @gotube It clearly shows you follow different grammar than I do. But I wan to clarify a few things. I did not say "aiming: is a Gerund or a noun phrase. As for the term Gerund-Participle, it is something that modern grammar use. You might not know it. And for your information, Google doesn't know anything, it is people like you and me that make it know. By the way Google does "know" it, ask it more and in a more polite way :-)

Comment: I was not able to find anything for "Gerund-Participle ***clause***".

Comment: @gotube In my google search I did find some. In here there are so many posts related to that.

Comment: Links or it never happened